# Run away variable

Tags: game-maker

i have a small function in a collision event in Game Maker, for some reason once triggered, the variable is supposed to increment, by another variable, it just runs off and keeps increment to max. here is the code.

```
if(global.rep <= 5000){
    global.rep +=  rep_gain;
    global.poop_time = poop_time - 5;
}
```

if this is in a collision event it should only fire once, the variable rep_gain is an irandom(5,10), but it will just keep running to 5000 which is max.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Just spitballing here, but are you sure this piece of code isn't being called multiple times? That small chunk of code doesn't look like it will execute by itself continuously. What's the rest of your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

In game maker, the collision event is constantly called until the collision is addressed by making the 2 objects no longer collide. if you don't do this, then the variable will increment until max.